# Как правильно настроить редирект?

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

как настроить редирект с https://mysite.ru./ на https://mysite.ru/
Вот пробовала это:

## RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.ru$

## RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.ru/$1 [L,R=301]

Получается ошибка. Как вот с этого редиректить сайт https://mysite.ru. когда на конце точка?
Спасибо!!!!!

Comment: пхпхпх, зачем?))

Comment: Клиент так хочет. Объяснять и тп. им бесполезно. Просто сказали надо